# How to change filename inside a rule? (Vue CLI 5)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-5

I have this rule, using `vue inspect`

```js
      /* config.module.rule('svg') */
          {
            test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
              filename: 'img/[name][ext]'
            }
          },
```

I need to change filename for example to "[contenthash][ext]"
but I cannot do it using

```js
    module.exports = defineConfig({
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rule("svg").generator.filename = "[contenthash][ext]";
      },
    })
```

because I cannot set generator ,

I can rewrite all rules using

```js
    module.exports = defineConfig({
    configureWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules = [
          {
            test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "svg-inline-loader",
                options: {
                  name: "[contenthash].[ext]",
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ];
    },
  })
```

but I need other rules to exist... so how can I change fileName of svg?

Comment: Is this (not yet released) Vue CLI 5?

Comment: yes, it is Vue CLI 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config.module.rule("svg")
    .set('generator', {
      filename: "[contenthash][ext]"
    })
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/assets.js#L19-L21)